# Is it possible to make Excel automatically copy a whole csv into a spreadsheet whenever the csv is updated?

Tags: excel

An application outputs data as a CSV file. I then open the CSV file in Excel and then copy and paste the contents into spreadsheet of an Excel worbook. The workbook has spreadsheets which process the data and draw graphs.

I am having to manually open the CSV file and copy its contents into the workbook, each time the CSV file is updated. This is tedios. Also, if the CSV file is open and I try to write to it, the application gives error. This means, I have to close the CSV file after copying data. I have done this a few dozen times and want an alternative solution.

Is it possible that Excel automatically copies data from the CSV file into a spreadsheet in the workbook, whenever the CSV file is updated?

Comment: Do you want Excel to be triggered when you open Excel, or to be triggered when the application outputs data?  Or, perhaps, once daily (etc)?

Comment: When it is opened and, when it is open and the CSV file is updated. In these two cases, the CSV must be copied into a spreadsheet in the Excel workbook. The remaining spreadsheets in the workbook shall do the rest.

Comment: Without attempting to solve your issue directly, have you tried inserting the CSV file using the DATA / Connections tool within Excel?  Then you could set the properties of your connection to refresh whenever Excel is opened.

Comment: I don't know what that even is

Comment: Try something for me... up on the ribbon, go to the DATA tab and click "Get External Data".  Then choose "from TEXT" and open your CSV file.

Comment: Use the file import menu to set the way Excel will read the CSV file...

Comment: Then, for trials, make a change to the CSV file.  Now click DATA > Refresh All @ Connections.

Comment: If this works, then go to DATA > Connections and use the properties window to decide when Excel should update itself from the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Macros will be your best friend.

First turn on your developer tab in the excel options. [image: Excel Options]

Now go to the tab at the top that says Developer. You will see "Record Macro" button and there is also one that is called "Visual Basic". It might be easier as a beginner to open the sheets that you want and then click the record and it will track what you do and then once you click stop it will save a file that does the work.

You can try and edit the following to suit your needs.

```
Sub CopyIn()
Dim CurrWB As Variant
CurrWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Dim StartSheet As Variant
StartSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
Dim CurrSheet As Variant
CurrSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
Dim CurrCol As Variant
Dim CurrRow As Variant
CurrCol = ActiveCell.Column
CurrRow = ActiveCell.Row

Dim Closing As Variant
If CurrWB = "yourCSVfile" Then
Closing = MsgBox("Critical Error" & Chr(10) & "Looks like the CSV download sheet is currently selected" & Chr(10) & "Cannot import into the CSV's download" & Chr(10) & Chr(9) & Chr(9) & "...Closing import tool now", vbCritical, "Importing Error")
Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks("yourCSVfile").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks(CurrWB).Activate
Sheets(CurrSheet).Select

Cells(CurrRow, CurrCol).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
    False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'closes the CSV file
'
'Uncomment the below lines to close the CSV file at the end
'
'Windows("yourCSVfile").Activate
'ActiveWindow.Close

Workbooks(CurrWB).Activate
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized

End Sub
```

Hope this is helpful. You will need to change the "yourCSVfile to the actual title of the file. The above will copy the file to whatever sheet you have open. I typically do this with a file that is already .xlsx so you might need to make some edits to deal with the CSV file. Lastly, you can save this code to either that specific spreadsheet and then that will be a macro enables sheet, but in the event that you do not want to do that you can save the code to your personal macro workbook and then you can use it when you open any file.

The code here is a starting point and will probably need some additional edit to make it work. If you have more information with the file names and tab names they can be added into the code.